# list creation with set elements

Tags: python, list, copy

Example says it all:

```
x = [set()]*5
x[0].add(1)
print x
```

yields:

```
[set([1]), set([1]), set([1]), set([1]), set([1])]
```

I understand what happened, but is this expected? Do I really need to use a loop to initialize a list with empty sets that are not aliases of each other?

Comment: Whether that's expected depends on who is expecting. Some people do, some people don't. Strange question.

Comment: What is strange about: "Do I really need to use a loop to initialize a list with empty sets that are not aliases of each other?"

Comment: If someone also answers the second question with just Yes or No, that poster will get the vote.

Comment: Thank Karin. The question linked is also a duplicate which directs to another duplicate... This seems to be a common issue I gather. I traced it to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly as the first question of which all are duplicates. I still have a second question open: Can this be done without loops?

Comment: Yes, you need to use a loop, eg `x = [set() for _ in range(5)]`; your code creates a list of 5 references to the one `set` object. Or you could do it without a loop: `x=[set(), set(), set(), set(), set()]` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand what happened, but is this expected?

This behavior is expected in Python.  Using the `*` operator in this context creates references to the `set()` objects, which means that when you change one such object (like you did with your `add()`), you change *all* of the references to that object.

> Do I really need to use a loop to initialize a list with empty sets that are not aliases of each other?

Yes; this is the proper way to create separately-referenced objects.